# I need to have multiple values passed in search box in grafana application logs dashboard

Tags: kubernetes, grafana, elasticsearch-dsl, grafana-variable

I need to have multiple values passed in search box in grafana application logs dashboard. currently i am using below query to search for a keyword in logs panel.

`kubernetes.namespace:$namespace AND kubernetes.pod.name:$pod AND stream:$log_stream AND message:/.*$search.*/`

Datasource: `Elasticsearch 7.6.1`[image: attaching image of k8s logs dashboard]

This will take only single string and does not accept multiple strings. I need regex to search for anything (includes special character, alphanumeric etc) in the logs.

Answer (score 1):

Use advance variable format in the query, which is suitable for Lucene - Elasticsearch. E.g.:

```
${variable:lucene}
```

Doc: https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/variables/advanced-variable-format-options/#lucene---elasticsearch

Comment: Did you mean something like this?
```/.*${variable:lucene}.*/```